# Iterate over the data to show Autocomplete suggestions

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

This is an API which returns results in an array, for auto suggestions

For Eg. if I query "google" I get the results as follows

```
["google","google maps","google translate","google earth","google images","google docs","google voice","google scholar","google chrome","google calendar",]
```

You can try it yourself [here](http://teckzone.in/q.php?q=google)

Here's my code that I m using to query this API but it doesnt seem to return results.

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/SmmnP/) the code that I m using for it

```
     $(function() {

    $( "#city" ).autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "q.php",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    "q" : request.term
                },
                success: function( data ) {
                    response(data[1]);
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2
    });
});
```

I dont understand where am I going wrong in the code
Please correct me ! Because it doesnt seem to be working as I wanted

Edit: Accessing the Data from the same server

Comment: How do you get the related words ? is this a free service ? can you give the url please ?

Comment: ofcourse it wont work because 1.) you did not check "jQuery UI" in the frameworks to add 2.) it's cross-domain. you are testing on jsFiddle and you are requesting data outside jsFiddle

Comment: I m just showing the code on JsFiddle.

Comment: I m testing it on my local server

Comment: And yeah it is a free service. Just query http://teckzone.in/q.php?q= The "q" will be the query parameter

Comment: then did you check your console what's happening? or check the network tab if you are actually receiving this form of JSON?

Comment: @NarendraRajput I meant what is the true url behind the scene ....

Comment: you are testing on a local server - same-origin policy still takes effect. you can't request from another domain.

Comment: Edited: Now I have a script which I m querying on the same domain

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add jquery-ui library in your fiddle. But if you do code will not work anyway, because you can't access data from another domain via ajax request. Only from same domain on what js code executes.

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.getJSON('http://twitter.com/users/usejquery.json?callback=?', function(json) { //get information about the user usejquery from twitter api
$('#twitter_followers').text(json.followers_count); //get the follower_count from the json object and put it in a span
});
});
```

Look for something called as cross-domain ajax.
http://usejquery.com/posts/the-jquery-cross-domain-ajax-guide

Answer (score 0):

You can read here about using jQuery autocomlete for cross-domain environment: http://1300grams.com/2009/08/17/jquery-autocomplete-with-json-jsonp-support-and-overriding-the-default-search-parameter-q/

Also you need to add jquery.autocomplete.js to your jsFiddle environment.